# Multiple Python Version Multiple Modules

Tags: python, macos

I have installed on Mac OS X 10.10:

I have installed Python 2.7.6 default apple
2.7.9 python mac ports
and
Pypy.

When i type `pip freeze` there a lot of modules installed.
However i can import some modules on one python and not the other one, because not everybody finds all modules.

Can someone explain me how can i achieve that every python version find every installed module?

(and does pip show all installed modules?)

As far as i can tell all modules are at : /Library/Python/2.7/sites-packages. But i don't know why not every python looks there.

Answer (score 0):

How about using virtualenv to manage multiple python? https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/
If you are not sure about which module you are importing, you could try to print the **file** of the module ( if the module has this attribute). eg:

```
macbook:~ mac$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PyQt4 as f
>>> print f.__file__
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/__init__.pyc
```

python will search the PYTHONPATH setting and try to load the module, if there are multiple python module with same name, it actually loads the 1st one.